NameError: Variable is not defined although it is defined and was working before
My code was working until now(it made a valid graph), but now I wanted to add soem other things and it says that the ages variable is not defined?
the dataset 
by_regions = akims.loc[~akims.region.isin(['Turkestan region', 'Zhetisu region'])].groupby('region')

plt.style.use('seaborn-v0_8')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(7, 2, figsize = (20, 40), sharex = True, sharey = True)
axs = axs.flatten()  
colormap = matplotlib.colormaps.get_cmap('viridis')

for i, (region, group) in enumerate(by_regions):
    ax = axs[i]
    mean = []
    for idx, row in akims.loc[akims.region == region].iterrows():
        
        color = colormap(float(f'0.{idx}') + 0.1)
        years = row['years_unpacked']
        born = row['year_born']
        
        if isinstance(years, list) :
            ages = [year - born for year in years]
            for age in ages:
                mean.append(age)
            # ax.scatter(years, ages, color = color,  label=f'{row['name']}')
        elif isinstance(years, int):
            ages = years - born
            mean.append(ages)
            
        ax.scatter(years, ages, color = color,  label=f'{row['name']}')
        
    ax.set_title(f'{region}, the average age: {np.median(mean)}', fontsize = 18)
    # ax.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.3), ncol=3)

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1, 0.97])
plt.suptitle("Mayors of Kazakhstan regions", fontsize=20)
# plt.savefig('region_mayors_final.png')

plt.show()

i tried it before and there was no such problem.

Please provide the full error message (and traceback) as text in an [edit]. Also, sample data should preferably be in the text of your question, not an external link.

If years is not a list or an int, then ages will not be defined. So a good first debugging step would be to add a third else branch to the if...elif statement, and print out the type of years so you can identify the problem. (Then you'll have to figure out what about your data causes years to be so defined).

Thanks for including a link to the data, but the code in the question should enable people to reproduce the described problem. I think that all that's missing is various imports and something that loads the CSV into the akims variable.

Please share a [mre]

When loading the .csv file the years is read as class 'str'. You can check this by adding an else condition to the if, elif cases
    else:
        print(f"{idx}, {years}, {type(years)}")

And you will get:
0, [1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997], <class 'str'>
Hence, one solution is to cast all the years into a list and then simplify your condtions:
from ast import literal_eval
# your other imports and loads
for idx, row in akims.loc[akims.region == region].iterrows():
        
        color = colormap(float(f'0.{idx}') + 0.1)
        years = row['years_unpacked']
        born = row['year_born']
        
        # Ensure 'years' is a list
        if isinstance(years, int):
            years = [years]
        elif isinstance(years, str):
            years = literal_eval(years)
        
        ages = [year - born for year in years]
        mean.extend(ages)
        
        ax.scatter(years, ages, color=color, label=f'{row["name"]}')
# your plots

